# Firebase: Verification email stops sending after a few times

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there some kind of anti spam on the verification emails?

I sent max 10 in a few minutes to the same email account.

I have to do this to test my registration flow.

Does anyone know of limits that they set?

The plan limits themselves are 1000/mails per day. I have definetely not exceeded those.

I have also tested different email adresses but none of them seem to be receiving any emails.

The sendEmailVerification() Promise resolves each time.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/bn4gFKCyKBk

Comment: I just received an email about an hour later. This is not acceptable for my registration process. Whats going on?

Comment: Are you using custom email domain?

Comment: No, nothing custom.